# Converting rough R console output into an R file

Tags: r

I am trying to work with a rough file that contains sensitive data (meaning the real version cannot be posted) where the person has provided the copy pasted code and output of an r file in the r console, which looks absolutely awful. Basically it looks something like this, but imagine thousands of lines

```
> #here are some comments  
> 
> data(mtcars)
> install.packages("dplyr")
Installing package into �C:/Users/Home/Documents/R/win-library/3.6�
(as �lib� is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/dplyr_0.8.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3227917 bytes (3.1 MB)
downloaded 3.1 MB

package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Home \AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpAnZJhs\downloaded_packages
> 
> 
> #let's look at some data 
> dim(mtcars)
[1] 32 11
> 
> #here is how to do a linear model 
> lm(disp ~ mpg, data=mtcars)

Call:
lm(formula = disp ~ mpg, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          mpg  
     580.88       -17.43  

> summary(lm(disp ~ mpg, data=mtcars))

Call:
lm(formula = disp ~ mpg, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-103.05  -45.74   -8.17   46.65  153.75 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  580.884     41.740  13.917 1.26e-14 ***
mpg          -17.429      1.993  -8.747 9.38e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 66.86 on 30 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7183,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.709 
F-statistic: 76.51 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 9.38e-10
```

The person does not have the old code, but says there's an easy way to fix this in any code IDE, but I don't think Rstudio has functionality to read only the parts with the `>` and turn that into an R file. I was trying to turn this file into a text file into python and read it line by line, but that didn't really seem to be working. I'm willing to take any sort of solution that can turn this mess into an R file or even a text file that could be copy pasted into R and run without all the terrible console output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below appraoch, with given input I have written the code, save the entire code text in a file called text.txt, then do the following

```
rd <- readLines('text.txt')

code_part <- grep('^>.+$', rd, value=TRUE)
code_part <- trimws(gsub('^>', '', code_part))

writeLines(paste(code_part, collapse = '\n'), 'file.txt')
```

The final file 'file.txt' will contain the code part written in R as a text file. This file should be present in your current working directory. Please try let me know if you need more help.

**Output at my end in the file.txt:**

```
#here are some comments

data(mtcars)
install.packages("dplyr")


#let's look at some data
dim(mtcars)

#here is how to do a linear model
lm(disp ~ mpg, data=mtcars)
summary(lm(disp ~ mpg, data=mtcars))
```